# Pyspark - How to merge multiple json stream to a single dataframe based on condition?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, pyspark

I have following json events from different streaming topic

```
customer= [

    {
        "Customer_id": "103",
        "Customer_name": "Hari",
        "email_address": "hari@gmail.com"
    }]

product = [
  {
    "Customer_id": "103",
    "product_id": " 205",
    "product_name": "Books",
    "product_Category": "Stationary"
  }]

Sales= [
  {
    "customer_id": "103",
    "line": {
      "product_id": "205",
      "purchase_time": "2017-08-19 12:17:55-0400",
      "quantity": "2",
      "unit_price": "25000"
    },
    "shipping_address": "Chennai"
  }]
```

above streaming are coming as different topic with below use case

1. when user login to the e-portal - customer.json
2. when user serach for the product - product.json
3. when user checkout for the product - sales.json

i created below DF for above use case

```
sales_schema = StructType([
    StructField("Customer_id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Customer_name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("email_address", StringType(), True),
    StructField("product_Category", StringType(), True),
    StructField("product_id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("product_name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("purchase_time", StringType(), True),
    StructField("quantity", StringType(), True),
    StructField("unit_price", StringType(), True),
    StructField("shipping_address", StringType(), True)
   ]
)
cus_Topic=session.sparkContext.parallelize(customer)
sales_df = session.createDataFrame(cus_Topic,sales_schema)

product_topic = session.sparkContext.parallelize(product)
productDF = session.createDataFrame(product_topic)

sales_df.show()

|Customer_id|Customer_name|   email_address|product_Category|product_id|product_name|purchase_time|quantity|unit_price|shipping_address|
         103|         Hari|  hari@gmail.com|            null|      null|        null|         null|    null|      null|            null|
         104|        Umesh|Umesh3@gmail.com|            null|      null|        null|         null|    null|      null|            null|


productDF.show()

+-----------+----------------+----------+------------+
|Customer_id|product_Category|product_id|product_name|
+-----------+----------------+----------+------------+
|        103|      Stationary|       205|       Books|
|        104|     Electronics|       206|      Mobile|
+-----------+----------------+----------+------------+
```

Now i want to merge this dataframe based on the customer_id

```
product_search_DF = sales_df.join(productDF, [sales_df.Customer_id==productDF.Customer_id], 'left_outer')
product_search_DF.show()

+-----------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------+----------+----------------+-----------+----------------+----------+------------+
|Customer_id|Customer_name|   email_address|product_Category|product_id|product_name|purchase_time|quantity|unit_price|shipping_address|Customer_id|product_Category|product_id|product_name|
+-----------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------+----------+----------------+-----------+----------------+----------+------------+
|        104|        Umesh|Umesh3@gmail.com|            null|      null|        null|         null|    null|      null|            null|        104|     Electronics|       206|      Mobile|
|        103|         Hari|  hari@gmail.com|            null|      null|        null|         null|    null|      null|            null|        103|      Stationary|       205|       Books|
+-----------+-------------+----------------+----------------+----------+------------+-------------+--------+----------+----------------+-----------+----------------+----------+------------+
```

But it makes duplicate column

Additionally, what iam looking is, from live streaming topic all these data from customer, product and sales should be merged to a single dataframe

I also would like to know the right approach to achieve this..

Appreciated for the help..
Thanks

Comment: I am afraid that I did not understand your question fully, are you looking for how to extract the json data into a Dataframe ? Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Hi @dsk i have updated my question, ideally i need to join different json streaming to a single dataframe

Comment: HI @dsk .. Hope the question makes more understandable..can you help us

Comment: There are two things here. 1) Why are you storing customer details with the schema of sales where all others fields are getting populated as null? Just store customer  with customer schema having 3 customer fields and then do the left outer join, you will not get these duplicate columns. 2) If you have any specific reason to do so (populating customer schema with extra fields which will always be null), then in the end you can just do a select on the joined dataframe and only select the fileds that you need from each of the dataframes.

Comment: Hi @SD3.. i need all these 3 topic (customer, product, sales) should be merged to a single dataframe. ie sales_df. so in  sales_df ,it will have consolidated data about the customer events, so further  i can apply transformation as per the requirement.. 
Correct me, if this approach is not right, when receive  live streaming to a data frame.. Thanks

Comment: HI @SD3 i tired with first approach with 'leftouter', but the duplicate not seems to removed.. 
product_serach_anlys = customerDF.join(productDF, customerDF.Customer_id == productDF.Customer_id,'left_outer')

Comment: @Adhi, When you want to do left outer join on streamimng dataframes, you need to use watermark and time constarints as well. Refer https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#stream-stream-joins. Also, in the your code sample, you are creating static dataframes and not the streaming dfs. And your duplicate columns issue should be solved either with removing duplication in schema or on selection in the end.